# Calculate Bollinger Z-score using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator

Given a series, I want to calculate its Bollinger Z-score (not the Bollinger band) using Pandas. There exists a prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74283043/) which discusses how to calculate the band, but not the z-score.

Given a variable `series` of type `pandas.Series` with dtype `float64`, I have the formula for calculating the z-score using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52187368/):

```
zs = (data - SMA(data, n=20)) / SD(data, n=20)
```

The above formula however is not Pandas code which I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this function. Its output looks to match that of TradingView.

```
import pandas as pd

def bollinger_zscore(series: pd.Series, length: int = 20) -> pd.Series:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499303/
    rolling = series.rolling(length)
    mean = rolling.mean()
    std = rolling.std(ddof=0)
    return (series - mean) / std
```

To calculate the Bollinger bands instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74283044/).